# Is it ok to leave partitions as is when installing from Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, uefi

Here is a picture of my [image: gparted]. I know I need to leave the efi alone, but I do not know what to do with the rest? Windows will be used to get free space and used to install ubuntu I do not plan on dual booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition labeled `recovery` will be your actual windows installer since windows doesn't ship with CDs anymore. The parition `TI10686800A` is your `C:\` (you're clearly using a toshiba laptop). If you ever plan to put windows back on this device I highly recommend you image your disk first as once the OEM recovery/installer is gone your options become limited.

If you do not plan to keep windows around you can completely wipe the disk, there is no need to keep around anything as Ubuntu supports EFI boot and will install the EFI loader for you.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Will I have to remove the EFI partition if its already there or would I just make a new one with more space? And if I leave the recovery partition alone I cant use that to reinstall windows?

Comment: Ubuntu needs to install it's own bootloader which will not support booting into the recovery parition without some additional work after the fact. Each system is different and it is best to image the disk first to ensure it is usable later. If you want to be really sure, you could just purchase a new hdd and install it for ubuntu use, preserving the original. You should not need to retain the original EFI anything, ubuntu will handle it all during the install.